# invariant violation error when using ReactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following relay-101 for starting help with relay. When I run the below code I got an invariant violation error.

**webpack.config.js:**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.js'),

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {stage: 0}
      }
    ]
  },

  output: {filename: 'index.bundle.js', path: './'}
};
```

**index.js**

```
let React = require('react');
let ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

class Item extends React.Component{
  render(){
    let item = this.props.store.item;

    return (
      <div>
         <h1><a href={items.url}>{item.title}</a></h1>
         <h2>{item.score} - {item.by.id}</h2>
         <hr />
      </div>
      );
  }
};

let mountNode = document.getElementById('contain');
let item = {
  id : '1337',
  url : 'http://google.com',
  title : 'Google',
  score : 100,
  by : {id : 'clay'}
};
let store = {item};
let rootComponent = <Item store={store} />;
ReactDOM.render(rootComponent, mountNode);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='contain'>
  </div>
  <script src="/index.bundle.js"  charset="utf-8" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the above I got an error like this:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: what's in console.log(mountNode) ?

Comment: @Francios Richard: it giving Null

Comment: so here is your problem, maybe doctype html missing  or something not loading properly

Comment: @Francios Richard:i added doctype html even though same error is coming

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have not specified the HTML file as an entrypoint in your Webpack config. Webpack is synthesizing one on the fly to load `index.js`, and most definitely, that file won't contain `<div id="contain"></div>`.

You can learn how to use the [Webpack HTML plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates) to write your own custom templates, but almost certainly the easiest thing will be to generate the mountpoint at runtime.

```js
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

class Item extends React.Component {
  render(){
    let item = this.props.store.item;
    return (
      <div>
         <h1><a href={items.url}>{item.title}</a></h1>
         <h2>{item.score} - {item.by.id}</h2>
         <hr />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

// Create the mount point and attach it to the DOM
const mountNode = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(mountNode);

const item = {
  id: '1337',
  url: 'http://google.com',
  title: 'Google',
  score: 100,
  by: {id: 'clay'},
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <Item store={{item}} />, 
  mountNode
);
```

Answer (score -2):

href={items.url} should be href={item.url}. Otherwise it runs on my setup. Your tool chain may have problems but I don't use webpack so don't see it.